# Ansible scanning Github branches

Tags: git, ansible

While setting up my Jenkins instance with Ansible to connect to our local GitHub Enterprise instance, I need to recreate what the Github Branch Plugin does to scan an Organizations projects and pre-create the directory structure for all valid projects.  I have a solution using multiple levels of include_tasks which is shown below:

main.yml

```
---
# tasks file for create-organisation-repos
- name: get the all repositories for your organisation
  uri:
    url: "{{ organisation.repos_url }}"
    method: GET
    user: "{{ github.username }}"
    password: "{{ github.password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: json
  register: organisation_repos

- debug: var=organisation_repos

- set_fact:
    repositories: "{{ organisation_repos.json }}"

- name: create each repository
  include_tasks: create-repo.yml
  loop: "{{ repositories }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: repository

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.branches_url | regex_replace('\\{.*\\}', '') }}"
  loop: "{{ organisation_repos.json }}"
```

create-repo.yml

```
---

- name: "create folders for repo {{ repository.name }} with default branch {{ repository.default_branch }}"
  file:
    name: "{{ organisation_config_dir }}/{{ github.organisation }}/jobs/{{ repository.name }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755

- name: "create the repo {{ repository.name }}"
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ organisation_config_dir }}/{{ github.organisation }}/jobs/{{ repository.name }}/{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ job_config_files }}"

- name: "get the branches for {{ repository.name }}"
  uri:
    url: "{{ repository.url }}/branches"
    method: GET
    user: "{{ github.username }}"
    password: "{{ github.password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: json
  register: branches
  failed_when: false

- set_fact:
    branches="{{ branches.json }}"

- debug: var=branches

- name: Create branch job
  include_tasks: create-branch.yml
  loop: "{{ branches }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: branch
```

create-branch.yml

```
---

- set_fact:
    branch_name: "{{ branch.name | regex_replace('/','-') }}"

- name: "get branch_info for {{ branch.name }}"
  uri:
    url: "{{ repository.url }}/branches/{{ branch.name }}"
    method: GET
    user: "{{ github.username }}"
    password: "{{ github.password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: json
  ignore_errors: true
  register: branch_info

- debug: var=branch_info

- name: "Does the Jenkinsfile exist for this branch"
  uri:
    url: "{{ repository.url }}/contents/{{ jenkinsfile_name }}?ref={{ branch.name }}"
    method: GET
    user: "{{ github.username }}"
    password: "{{ github.password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
  ignore_errors: true
  register: jenkinsfile
  when: branch_info is success

- debug: var=jenkinsfile

- name: "directory is present for {{ branch.name }}"
  file:
    name: "{{ organisation_config_dir }}/{{ github.organisation }}/jobs/{{ repository.name }}/branches/{{ branch_name }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
  when: jenkinsfile is success

- name: copy configuration files for branch
  template:
    src: "branch/{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ organisation_config_dir }}/{{ github.organisation }}/jobs/{{ repository.name }}/branches/{{ branch_name }}/{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ branch_config_files }}"
  when: jenkinsfile is success
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to get a list of branches which contain a Jenkinsfile, but I cannot work out how to build the list and filter it.

There must be a simpler solution.  Anyone?